# How to make a programmer implement the right callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, libraries

I wonder if it is possible to show a library user that a function needs a callback with let's say 5 parameters 3 of which are arrays (for example).
Or in other words, how to inform the programmer not to mess up with the callback arguments?
Here's a code example:

```
function doSomething(someArray, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < someArray.length; i += 1) {
        callback(someArray[i]);
    }
}
```

How a programmer would find out what parameters should their callback function accept?

Comment: You mean like intellisense? (From the Wikipedia page - " IntelliSense is a convenient way to access descriptions of functions, particularly their parameter lists")

Comment: it is not possible to declare parameter types in javascript, not even declaring of argument count is possible, so its up to the programmer to make a lot of typechecking, or just documenting it.

Comment: This is what documentation is for.

Comment: It's not impossible, but it would require static code analysis to point out such mistake. I am not aware of any tools can now do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript does not have type checking for arguments and there is no way for you to do runtime checking of a callback to see what arguments it is expecting.  One thing you can do at runtime is you can check `callback.length` to see how many arguments it has declared that it is expecting as formal parameters.  It is not required for a function to define it's formal parameters as it can also use the arguments object to get the arguments, but if you wanted to force them to program a certain way, you could check it this way.  See [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) for more info.

Your best option is good documentation to make it absolutely clear (often with sample code too) how a callback should be written.

If you want to bulletproof your library a bit, you could catch any exceptions that were thrown in the callback and handle them however is appropriate.

```
function doSomething(someArray, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < someArray.length; i += 1) {
        try {
            callback(someArray[i]);
        } catch(e) {
            // handle any exception in the callback
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess not only seeing what arguments but also how many is also not possible. Thanks jfriend00 and philipp.

Comment: @NikolaGeneshki - I added some info about `callback.length` to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By documenting it. Usually documented convention works as good as having a enforced contract via language. At-most you can pass a single object to callbacks and that object can have named attributes e.g.

```
callback({'names':[], 'types':[], value:0, etc:[] })
```

That way it is more easy for both side code to be well documented.